# Using css to animate graphics entering and then orbiting a central graphic

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I have a website design where I have 7 graphics (all the same dimensions). The requirement is for them to fly in from the side in a line, following a slightly curved path. The first one will go to the middle, the others will then enter an orbit around the first one until all 6 are surrounding it evenly, at which point they all stop. Finally, the central graphic needs to pulse.

I'm not sure if I have explained that very well!

Unfortunately, there are several of these, with different graphics, so I don't want to simply make it as an animated gif, or whatever. I have seen several posts showing, for example, how to use CSS to show a spacecraft continually orbiting a planet, or to follow a curved path, but can I set this up in the way I describe? How do I make to "story" go through the phases?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS offset-path or motion-path, you can create a different path for each of the elements. Adding a delay to movement of each element, I think you can create such an animation.

Creating a path for each element won't be easy but [here](http://usefulangle.com/post/33/moving-element-in-circular-path-with-css-offset-path) is a tutorial on achieving animation on a circular path using CSS offset-path.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

I need to review that tutorial fully :-)